# Dynamically generating site info based on the URL used to get there

Tags: reactjs, redux, dynamic, hosting, react-context

I am currently working on a contract site for a financial planning company.

For some context:

The site will allow their clients to sign up for the companies monthly webinars by making requests to an API for Webinarjam.com

The client side is a very simple one page site built with React. It includes info about the webinar, info about the presenter of the webinar and the form to sign up.

I have a simple proxy server (NodeJS(Express)) that makes the requests to the WebinarJam api on the back end. Along with a single table PostgreSQL DB that will save the attendees info for the company's reference. (name, email, phone, webinar attended, etc.)

The site is completely built and ready to be hosted and thus my question.

#### My question

The site will be used by 5 different presenters at the company. They would each like to have their own link and be able to send that link to their specific clients. All the other info on the page would remain the same (Same webinar, same things discussed) only the presenter would change.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically render the info on a site based on the link that was used to
get there?

When the site first renders a request is made to Webinarjam's API for info on a specific webinar using the webinar's ID. This returns an object with all of the info about the webinar INCLUDING the presenter(s) info. (All the info displayed on the site is dynamically rendered from the data returned from this request)

So in theory, could the link 'john.webinar.com' reroute to 'webinar.com' and the site would render John's info as the presenter?

(I am currently using Context API for global state management, I also am comfortable with Redux if it is applicable for something like this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically render the info on a site based on the link that was used to get there?

Yes, absolutely! The [react-router](https://reactrouter.com) and [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) packages can make this easier and cleaner, but here's a way just with DOM methods.

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const presenter = query.get("presenter");
```

The `presenter` variable will either be the string from the URL or `null` if the URL didn't include one.

```
export default function App() {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const presenter = query.get("presenter");

  return (
    <div>
      {presenter ? (
        <h1>Presented By {presenter}</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>All Presentations</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you go to `mysite.com` then it renders "All Presentations" but if you go to `mysite.com/?presenter=John` then it renders "Presented By John".

A path-based link like `mysite.com/john` can be set up with react-router-dom.  If you want a subdomain like `john.mysite.com` then that requires additional configuration on your server (through `.htaccess` or similar).

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you!